# Kindle Fire navigator.getusermedia crashes it

Tags: android, cordova, audio, audio-recording, kindle-fire

I have a web app that records audio only. I'm using phonegap to make it into an android app. It works fine on all devices except on the Kindle Fire. If it supports web audio I use web audio, otherwise I use java AudioTrack. Kindle Fire seems to support web audio because navigator.getUserMedia exists.

I run on a Kindle Fire and in chrome console I enter:

```
navigator.getUserMedia(
                               {
                                   "audio": {
                                       "optional": []
                                   },
                               },
                               function(r){console.log(r)},
                               function(r){console.log(r)});
```

Result in Android Studio:

```
D/SystemWebChromeClient: onPermissionRequest: [android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE]
W/cr_zhichao_tot: AmazonVideoCaptureFactory getNumberOfCameras 11
Missing android.permission.CAMERA permission, no system camera available.
W/cr_zhichao_tot: AmazonVideoCaptureFactory getNumberOfCameras 22
W/cr_zhichao_tot: AmazonVideoCaptureFactory getDeviceName get id:0
W/cr_zhichao_tot: AmazonVideoCaptureFactory getDeviceName get 1
W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
W/google-breakpad: 3.2
W/google-breakpad: 11088
W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 11745
```

Then the app crashes. Any ideas how to detect that it's going to crash besides detecting Kindle Fire? None of the javascript callbacks are called. I don't need access to take pictures, just the microphone.